# On-site checkout vs "external" checkout

Tags: e-commerce, ux-field, checkout, payment, selling-ux

I have an small online store, built using Shopify. I've set it up all right, but because of my location,
**I can't use *Stripe, Authorize.net or any other popular*** payment gateways, which offer "on-site checkout", meaning a user stays on the same page during the entire checkout process.

The two alternatives are:

1. Use **another payment gateway**, which will redirect the users to another web page, where they can enter their credit cards data and checkout. The problem is that this page can't be customized more than just logo and colors.
2. Use **PayPal Express Checkout**, which gives the option to create a guest account and fill the data of your credit card. The problem is that it's a button that says [Create an account](http://prntscr.com/i2a1bu) and I'm pretty sure this will scare away buyers (they're required to "sign up" at the end of a purchase).

I couldn't find any data on which scenario has a higher conversion rate. Does anyone have experience with such issues and could share some helpful knowledge about what solution is better?

Comment: Hi Dennis, this question is borderline off-topic because without specific knowledge of your customers, answers will be primarily opinon-based. Obviously users convert less if they have to checkout on Paypal as opposed to natively (https://www.moovweb.com/paypal-convenient-tool-or-conversion-killer/) but how Paypal will compare to any other non-native experience can only be really known (for your site and your customers) by testing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have to use an off-site payment page, then use it to your advantage.  Bill it as "We use a trusted payment facilitator to ensure the safety of your payment information."

Comment: Looks so simple, but it didn't ever come to my mind :)

Comment: Honestly, I rarely purchase from an online retailer unless I visibly see they're using a third party payment provider. I don't trust entering my credit card info into RandomSmallBikeStore.com, because their primary concern is selling bike parts.  Card security is their least important thing to do.